# Definite Integral question, help!

Tags: calculus

What's the definite integral:
$$\int_0^{\pi/6} \frac{\sin(2x)}{\cos^2(2x)} d x$$
I make $u = \cos (2x)$, 
$du/dx = \frac{1}{2} \sin(2x)$, 
so $2 du = \sin(2x) dx$
and I get the answer $(-\frac{2}{3})\cos^{-3}(2x)$.

Am I doing everything correctly ? Because when I plug in $\frac{\pi}{6}$ to that answer I get some crazy decimal answer.

Comment: The function is $\tan(2x)/\cos(2x)$, that integral is divergent in that interval

Comment: One error: ${du\over dx}=-2\sin(2x)$, not ${1\over2}\sin (2x)$.

Comment: @MyUserIsThis: Why did you change the upper limit from the OP’s $\pi/6$ to $6\pi$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Did I? Total mistake, I'm sorry. I was going to say the integral should be zero because its period is $6\pi$, but if the upper limit is $\pi /6$ then I'm wrong... I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The substitution $u=\cos 2x$ is fine, but your computations are a bit off. First, $$\frac{du}{dx}=-2\sin2x\;,$$ $\cos 2(0)=1$, and $\cos\frac{\pi}3=\frac12$, so your integral becomes

$$\int_0^{\pi/6}\frac{\sin 2x}{\cos^2 2x}dx=-\frac12\int_1^{1/2}u^{-2}du\;.$$

Then you integrated incorrectly:

$$-\frac12\int_1^{1/2}u^{-2}du=-\frac12\left[\frac{u^{-1}}{-1}\right]_1^{1/2}=\frac12\left[\frac1u\right]_1^{1/2}=\frac12(2-1)=\frac12\;.$$

Comment: @jun: Neither one.

Comment: @user61618: Good to hear; you’re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, perform an integration by parts:

$$\begin{align} \int_0^{\pi/6} dx \: \sec^2{2 x} \sin{2 x} &= \frac{1}{2} [\tan{2 x} \sin{2 x}]_0^{\pi/6} - \int_0^{\pi/6} dx \: \tan{2 x} \cos{2 x} \\ &= \frac{\sin^2{\frac{\pi}{3}}}{2 \cos{\frac{\pi}{3}}} - \int_0^{\pi/6} dx \: \sin{2 x}\\ &=\frac{3/4}{2 (1/2)} - \frac{1}{2} \left(1-\cos{\frac{\pi}{3}}\right)\\ &= \frac{3}{4} - \frac{1}{4}\\ &=\frac{1}{2} \end{align}$$